# DataGridView selected row to check a checkbox

Tags: c#, sql, checkbox, datagridview

I am currently trying to check a checkbox dependent of the SQL data after selecting the row in a datagridview.

I have gotten this to display text with TexBoxes, but cannot get it to check a check box.

Yes = True
No = False

Any recommendations, would be very much appreciated.

```html
                textBox4.Text = row.Cells[11].Value.ToString();  //other/notes
                textBox3.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();  //Monitor
                textBox1.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();  //Firstname
                textBox2.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();  //Surname
                comboBox1.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();  //Company
                comboBox3.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();  //Laptop/Nuc
                checkBox1. = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();   //keyboard
```

[image]

```
enter code here
```

The table being displayed is  bound by'binding source' the code below is how the the datadridview is populated.

```html
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
bs.Filter = "Firstname Like '" + textBox1.Text + "%' and lastname Like '" + textBox2.Text + "%' and Company '" + comboBox1.Text + "%'";
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs.DataSource;
```

Comment: Ignore the labels next to the check boxes, they need to be removed

Comment: I am not sure if I am following what the grid contains. Is the grid data bound to something like a `DataTable` or `BindingSource`? And if so… I assume all the columns in the grids `DataSource` are of a “Text” type containing “Yes/No” and are NOT `bool` types containing `true/false`?

Comment: I have edited the question to hopefully, provide some more information.

All columns are a 'DataSource'  and is a 'text type'

Comment: So, I assume that the grid has numerous rows and is what you are wanting is that if the user “selects” a row in the grid, then the check boxes above the grid will set the corresponding check boxes to “checked” if the corresponding cell value is “Yes” and set the check box to “unchecked” if the cells value is set to “No” or any other value. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things I will assume and apply a certain logic that may not necessarily be what you want. However, it should be trivial to alter the code to meet your needs.

It appears the columns in the grids `DataSource` are “text/string” columns containing a “Yes/No” values or possibly no value at all. And if we wanted to make that column a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`, then, this is quite doable by setting the check box columns `TrueValue` property to `Yes` and `FalseValue` to `No`.

However, when attempting to “bind” the same column to an external regular `CheckBox` … this will create a `string` to `bool` cast error and that makes sense since it is looking for a `bool` value and does not have a `TrueValue` nor `FalseValue` property.

In addition, since the values in the grid cells may be “Yes”, “No” or possibly nothing… I set the regular external check boxes `ThreeState` property to `true`. This will allow three different states for the check boxes… 1) Checked for “Yes/yes”, 2) Unchecked for “No/no” and 3) Indeterminate meaning the cells value is either empty or has some other value other than “Yes” or “No.” The `Inderterminate` state is displayed in the check box with a black square in the check box as shown below.

So given this, below is a simple solution using a couple of the grid’s events. Namely the grid’s `RowEnter` event and the grid’s `CellValueChanged` event.

To help, I create a method that takes three arguments… an `int` row index, also an `int` column index and a regular `CheckBox`. This method simply checks the value of the cell in the grid at the given row and column index and sets the given `CheckBox` to the proper checked state. This method may look something like below…

```
private void SetCheckBox(int rowIndex, int colIndex, CheckBox cb) {
  string value;
  if (dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].Value != null) {
    value = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].Value.ToString();
  }
  else {
    value = "";
  }
  if (value.ToLower() == "yes") {
    cb.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
  }
  else {
    if (value.ToLower() == "no") {
      cb.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
    }
    else {
      cb.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate;
    }
  } 
}
```

As previously noted, if the cells value is empty or not a “yes” or “no” value… then the check box will be set with the indeterminate state. We will use this method in the grid’s `RowEnter` event and the grids `CellValueChanged` event. These events may look something like below…

```
private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if (e.RowIndex >= 0) {
    SetCheckBox(e.RowIndex, 0, checkBox1);
    SetCheckBox(e.RowIndex, 1, checkBox2);
    SetCheckBox(e.RowIndex, 2, checkBox3);
  }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if (e.RowIndex >= 0) {
    switch(e.ColumnIndex) {
      case 0:
        SetCheckBox(e.RowIndex, 0, checkBox1);
        break;
      case 1:
        SetCheckBox(e.RowIndex, 1, checkBox2);
        break;
      case 2:
        SetCheckBox(e.RowIndex, 2, checkBox3);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Below is a full example to give this a test… It should be noted, that since the `CheckBoxes` are enabled, then, the user could possibly check or uncheck one of the check boxes and possibly put the check boxes and the selected row in the grid into an inconsistent state. To prevent this, each check boxes `AutoCheck` property is set to `false` to prevent this.

[image]

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueChanged);
  dataGridView1.RowEnter += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_RowEnter);
  checkBox1.ThreeState = true;
  checkBox2.ThreeState = true;
  checkBox3.ThreeState = true;
  checkBox1.AutoCheck = false;
  checkBox2.AutoCheck = false;
  checkBox3.AutoCheck = false;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  DataTable GridDT = new DataTable();
  GridDT.Columns.Add("Check1", typeof(string));
  GridDT.Columns.Add("Check2", typeof(string));
  GridDT.Columns.Add("Check3", typeof(string));
  GridDT.Rows.Add("Yes", "No", "Yes");
  GridDT.Rows.Add("No", "Yes", "Yes");
  GridDT.Rows.Add("Yes", "No", "No");
  GridDT.Rows.Add("No", "Yes", "Yes");
  GridDT.Rows.Add("", "", "Yes");
  GridDT.Rows.Add("No", "Yes");
  BindingSource GridBS = new BindingSource();
  GridBS.DataSource = GridDT;
  dataGridView1.DataSource = GridBS;
  GridBS.ResetBindings(false);
}
```

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a work around. if you would like the text to be hidden, you can change the fore color of the checkbox.text

```html
 checkBox1.Text = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString(); //Keyboard
                if (checkBox1.Text == "Yes")
                    this.checkBox1.Checked = true;
                        else
                            this.checkBox1.Checked = false;
```